# How to run two scripts at a same time for Grove Pi?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, grovepi+

Currently I am using a GrovePi with 2 barometric sensors. I am wondering if there is a way to run two python codes from the command line at a time. Can anyone please help me?
I am using Linux operating system and running the code using command line. I am using,

```
sudo python script1.py &
            script2.py &
```

which gives

> bash: script2.py: command not found

How could I fix this?

[Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThGsd.png)

Comment: You have to give each command completely, not just part of the second one. `sudo python script1.py & sudo python script2.py`, assuming sudo doesn't need to prompt for a password. If it does, just `sudo startscript`, where _startscript_ is a simple shell script running both python scripts as above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bash, you can use the `&` shell operator to execute a process and tell it to go to the background, which you are using; however, what you are telling the interpreter is to execute `sudo python script1.py` and put it into the background, and then execute `script2.py` and put it into the background. Obviously, there is no command `script2.py`.

To fix this you need to put in the full command each time.

```
sudo python script1.py &
sudo python script2.py &
```

However, make sure that you *need* to use `sudo`, running a script with elevated permissions if it does not need them could be dangerous.